# SQLite code first and inverse property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, ef-code-first

I'm working with SQLite CodeFires EF 6.1.3 . Everything works fine, but I want to use inverse property.

I have 2 classes:

```
public sealed class Page
{
   ....
    [InverseProperty("PageOfThisKey")]
    public ICollection<Keys> KeysOfThisPage { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

and class Key:

```
public sealed class Key
{
   ...
    public Int32 PageID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PageID")]
    public Page PageOfThisKey { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

So what I want to be able to do is to take an instance of Page and get all Keys devoted to this page in the property. So to say - like this:

```
var db = ConnectionManager.GetContext();
var keys = db.Pages.First().KeysOfThisPage;
```

But 'keys' variable is always null.

I'm using code first and SQLite code first solution https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst

Can someone, please, take a look how is it possible to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use "virtual" keyword for enabling lazy loading like this :

```
public class Page
{
   ....
    [InverseProperty("PageOfThisKey")]
    public virtual ICollection<Keys> KeysOfThisPage { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class Key
{
   ...
    public Int32 PageID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageID")]
    [InverseProperty("KeysOfThisPage")]
    public virtual Page PageOfThisKey { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Or you can using "include" in linq query.

```
var keys = db.Pages.Include("KeysOfThisPage").First().KeysOfThisPage;
```

for more information see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: Thank you :) Just a small note - virtual keywork wont work with sealed class, so it should not be marked as sealed.